# can't test for input checked in each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a simple object of input checkbox elements and want to check in an each loop which ones are checked and the do stuff. The checkboxes are in one `tr` in several `td`'s in a table.

Here is my code:

```
$('table.occupancy-table').on('change', '.minimum_stay input', function() {
    var minimumStayInputs = $(this).closest('tr').find('input');
    $(minimumStayInputs).each(function(){
        if(this.prop('checked')) {
        //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

If I console.log `this` in the each loop, I get data like:

`<input id="R11520" type="checkbox" name="minimum_stay[152][1442786400]" value="checked">
<input id="R11521" type="checkbox" name="minimum_stay[152][1442872800]" value="checked">`...

But I always get an error `Uncaught TypeError: this.prop is not a function` from `this.prop('checked')`. I also tried `.is(":checked")` with the same result.

Any ideas what the reason might be?

Let me know if you need sample html or I should create  fiddle.

Comment: Try to replace `this.` with `$(this).`.

Comment: `.prop()` is a jQuery method. You'll need to say `$(this).prop('checked')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` inside the loop is the native DOM element, unwrapped from jQuery.

It has to be wrapped again

```
$('table.occupancy-table').on('change', '.minimum_stay input', function() {
    var minimumStayInputs = $(this).closest('tr').find('input');
    $(minimumStayInputs).each(function(){
        if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
        }
    });
});
```

You could also just use the native `this.checked`, or if you're trying to count them

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input:checked').length
```